# Switching between Core Data stores crashes the app on the iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, core-data, magicalrecord

In my iOS app I'm using two different Core Data stores (internal and external DBs). Everything works fine on simulator, but when I'm testing on the iPad I'm experiencing crashes. I figured out how to avoid crashes, but I don't understand how it works. I'm using Magical Record for my Core Data stack.

So, in my first version of the code DBs were created and initialized in different classes and I was using:

```
 [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextWithStoreCoordinator:self.psc];
```

to pick the right coordinator before talking to DB. It was working fine on simulator, but didn't work on the device.

Then, I switched to:

```
 [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
```

And it was giving me errors that I'm not using the right store for fetching.

Then, I moved all my DB's initializations and creations to the same class:

```
 NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [self databaseSetup];
 externalDB = [[HSDBManipulations alloc] initWithFileName:@"hData.hso" andPSC:psc]; 


 NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc2 = [self internalDBSetup];
 internalDB = [[HSInternalDB alloc] initWithFileName:@"internalDB" andPSC:psc2];
```

and this works fine!!!

However, when I switch the order of the DB creations like this:

```
 NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc2 = [self internalDBSetup];
 internalDB = [[HSInternalDB alloc] initWithFileName:@"internalDB" andPSC:psc2];

 NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [self databaseSetup];
 externalDB = [[HSDBManipulations alloc] initWithFileName:@"hData.hso" andPSC:psc];
```

it stops working on the device again, complaining about the wrong store accessed.

externalDB is the read only DB and it's located in the app bundle, internalDB is read/write and it's located in documents directory...

Any help is really appreciated!